# What is the "II" set operation called?

Tags: notation

I'm reading "General Topology" by Muller and he uses $$A \amalg B = \{(1, a) | a ∈ A\} ∪ \{(2, b) | b ∈ B\}.$$ Does this operation have a name or a different symbol? I've never seen it before.

Comment: Looks like a "disjoint union" or "co-product" Is the symbol exactly what you used here or rather $\coprod$ a flipped product sign?

Comment: Looking more closely, it is indeed a flipped product sign ∐. I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Out of interest, does Muller use $\amalg$ or $\sqcup$? $\amalg$ is usually used for the disjoint union of a family of sets, not just two sets (cf. $\sum$ v. $+$).

Comment: $\amalg$. He starts with "If A and B are sets..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol is actually $\coprod$, and this operation is called "disjoint union".  The idea is you are taking the union of $A$ and $B$, except you are forcing them to be disjoint sets first.  The symbol is kind of a pun.  On the one hand, it is a variant of the union symbol $\cup$.  On the other hand, it is an upside down version of the product symbol $\prod$, and $\coprod$ is also called the "coproduct" since it is dual in a certain sense to the Cartesian product of sets.

Comment: What do you mean by "dual in a certain sense to the Cartesian product"?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct.